# Use trigonometry in a triangle that is not right angled.

Tags: trigonometry

The following questions states that in a triangle ABC, every angle is acute and Sin(A)=0.6, what is Cos(b+c).

I'm confused, how is it possible to use sine and cosine if the triangle is not right angled?

Comment: Sine and cosine are just defined a different way for triangles that aren't right angled. Take a look at the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

Comment: Assuming that the labels for the three angles are $A,b,c$ you would have a total of $180^\circ$ as the sum of all three, so if you have $b+c$ you can also write that as...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin A = 0.6 = \frac{3}{5}$$

As $A$ is acute,

$$\cos A = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2}=\frac{4}{5}$$

Now, $$A+B+C=180^{\circ}$$
$$ \implies B+C = 180^{\circ}-A$$

Taking $\cos$ of both sides,

$$\cos(B+C) = \cos(180^{\circ}-A)=-\cos A$$

Hence $\cos(B+C)=-\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: I edited your answer into MathJax. If any of it isn't right you can feel free to fix it.